# Switching between setTimeout function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have setTimout function like this

```
    setTimeout(function(){
    //doing something here
},1000);
```

another setTimeout func like this right after the above func

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
        //code here
},10000);
```

What I need to achieve is I need to read some files in first setTimeout function and do some processing,once the timeout over control should go to second timeout function,do some stuff there.Then get back to the first timeout function,do some processing there,when timeout over callback the second fun and so on..Like that I need to do for n number of files.

But whats happening is if I give for loop inside the first setTimeout fun,it process all the files and control is passed to second timeout fun with the last processed file.But what i want is to do that for each file??

How can i achieve this?Am newbie in Javascript. Any help?

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you're trying to do when you describe it in such vague terms. Can you show the real processing code?

Answer (score 3):

```
function timeout1() {
  console.log("This is timeout 1");
  window.setTimeout(timeout2, 500);
}

function timeout2() {
  console.log("This is timeout 2");
  window.setTimeout(timeout1, 500);
}

// Kick it off.
timeout1();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two Time outs why didn't you use wait like below?

```
setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);
```

Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) for a detailed explanation.

Hope this helps.

Please leave a feed back.

Comment: Using `setInterval` is considered a bad idea. What if your operation doesn't complete in the time indicated? Or if there are errors, the interval would go on. It's better to invoke `setTimeout` inside another `setTimeout` function.